# How to find a TextView inside a view which is placed in a tab in android

Tags: android, view, android-tabhost

I have a view that has a tab.Inside each tab ,Im creating another view.

So the view that contains tab is created on an activity that is different from the activity that is used to create a view inside the tab.

How can I access the text for EditTextView placed inside the tab's view from the main activity?

Comment: post code samples that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *TabHost.TabSpec*.setIndicator(label) to customize the content of a tab.

**TabLayout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**How to implement (example snippets)**

```
// For each record I have, I want to display a Tab. 
for (Record r: myRecords) {
     setupTab(new TextView(mContext), r);
}


private void setupTab(final View view, final Record record) {
    TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(..ID..);
    tabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        return view;
    }
    });

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(mTabHost.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);

    // Find you TextView by ID and alter it.
    ((TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(record.getTitle());

    // Set is as indicator
    tabSpec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);

    // Add it to the TabHost
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

Comment: I want the the value of an editText inside one of the tab..i need to get the value in tabactivity